# Loops on SQL Select

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I have a problem, my PHP page make loops.

I select into my DB only 2 informations like this :

```
$sqlins="SELECT hardware.name, rd.cmd
FROM hardware, rd
WHERE hardware.name LIKE 'Boomee'
AND rd.cmd LIKE 'putty'";
$toto = mysql_query($sqlins);
```

It's an exemple of my request.
And when I use the loop While like this :

```
while ($data=mysql_fetch_array($toto)) {
    echo $data[1];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

I don't understand why my output send me many time the same line.
While on my DB, I have 30 entries. I want to display them all... but the code sended me 2700!

My real script is a bit more complicate than this, I use `preg_replace`, `implode` etc, and much more "`AND LIKE`" in my `SQL Query`.

I hope you can help me. And please help me.

Comment: Your SQL query is probably returning a cross join (cartesian product) of the 2 tables. You need to join them on a mutaul field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT hardware.name, rd.cmd
FROM hardware, rd
WHERE hardware.name LIKE 'Boomee'
AND rd.cmd LIKE 'putty'
```

perform a cartesian product.

If you don't want perform this action you must to put in relation your 2 tables hardware and rd.

I don't know if hardware is parent of rd or viceversa. But if exists a field to link two tables you add this condition in WHERE clause.

Alternatively (adviced) you rewrite your query with explicit JOIN in this way:

```
SELECT hardware.name, rd.cmd
FROM hardware
INNER JOIN rd
ON hardware.field = rd.field
WHERE hardware.name LIKE 'Boomee'
AND rd.cmd LIKE 'putty'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes i have 2 field linked in hardware and rd.

The first one is "hardware.id", and the second one "rd.hardware_id".

And your method work perfectly.

I have change my query like this, because i have to learn what is INNER JOIN and ON before using it.

```
SELECT hardware.name, rd.cmd
FROM hardware, rd
WHERE hardware.id=rd.hardware_id
AND hardware.name LIKE 'Boomee'
AND rd.cmd LIKE 'putty'
```

So thanks you a lot. by the same way it's gonna help me for the pursuit of link between table.